# Why is Chart.js forEach is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, chart.js

I am making a chart with chart.js but I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
>       at Object.

The code line where the error is coming from is this

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: 'link',
    dataType: 'json',
  }).done(function (results) {
    // Split timestamp and data into separate arrays
    var labels = [], data=[];
    results["packets"].forEach(function(packet) {
    labels.push(new Date(packet.timestamp).formatMMDDYYYY());
    data.push(parseFloat(packet.payloadString));
});
```

I don't see any problem why this is not working.

Comment: Hi, can you please add sample value of `results`?

Comment: Provide a null guard like this `results && results["packets"].forEach.....`

Comment: It's exactly what the error says - `results["packets"]` is `undefined`. You should check what's being returned by your AJAX call.

Comment: without seeing the data we can't be certain, but it seems the JSON is not returning what you expected. `console.log(JSON.stringify(results));` (or just checking the response from the ajax call in your browser's network tools) will allow you to see what data you're actually receiving. This is a fairly simple problem which is easily debuggable...you just need to learn how to use the tools already at your disposal, and then you'll find you can fix it much more easily.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal 0:
data:
NOK: {count: 0, percentage: 0}
OK: {count: "8", percentage: "100"}
__proto__: Object
timestamp: "1541404800"
__proto__: Object

Comment: @K.Jackson - I can not see `packets` property in the object that is why `forEach` of undefined error is coming.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Yes i see that also. This is the first time i am doing this and have found this small code on the online but do you know what there then need instead packets?

Comment: @K.Jackson - I have not worked on chart.js so not sure how to reach to the end result

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Okay thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

You've misread the error message.

It doesn't say `forEach` is undefined, it says that you are trying to read a property called `forEach` **from something else which is `undefined`**.

In this case that something is `results["packets"]`.

And it is undefined because the JSON you are getting back from `link` doesn't have the structure you think it does. You need to look at `results` (e.g. with `console.log(results)` and see what structure it actually has.

Comment: This is what the console.log gives.

0:
data:
NOK: {count: 0, percentage: 0}
OK: {count: "8", percentage: "100"}
__proto__: Object
timestamp: "1541404800"
__proto__: Object

Comment: @K.Jackson — No sign of anything called `packets` there.

Comment: Yes that's true that small code I have from someone else but what do I need to but there then for packets if you look at the json. This is the first time that i do this

Comment: @K.Jackson instead, use the name of the field you want to access :-). It seems you have an object with a  property called "data" which is itself an object, and then within that you have two properties "NOK" and "OK", etc. You didn't mention which bit of data you were hoping to use.

Comment: @ADyson I need to use the data of "NOK" and "OK". Can you give me a example how to do what you mean

Comment: @K.Jackson if you want to get at the property of an object then you simply just use its name. The code in the sample you've copied (clearly without understanding much of it) is expecting that the "results" object will contain a property named "packets". You haven't got that, so just need to change it to the name of something you _have_ got. It's really that simple! Since it seems you may have an array, try e.g. `var x = result[0].data.NOK;` (P.S. you can find tutorials about this kind of thing anywhere, it's pretty basic JS knowledge about regarding the use of objects).